# bash script to calculate average of several integer values

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a bash script that adds the current values and returns the average. When I run the script `./average` I get the error message: `missing}`. I am not sure why the script isn't printing the average to screen when I run it.

Here's what I have written thus far:

```
#! /bin/csh
for var in "${sum[store1=100, store2= 75, store3= 74, store4= 100, store5= 100])}"

do
total= $sum(store1+store2+ store3+store4+store5))


echo $sum / 5
done
```

Comment: Why the extra paren at the end of your `total=` assignment?

Comment: Why the extra paren at the end of your `for var in` loop?

Comment: "... bash script ..." "`#! /bin/csh`" Uh, no.

Comment: I cleared out the extra parens. Thanks Madbreaks for editing my question and alerting me to the extra parens. I think I got this figured out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed: (Updated)

```
#/bin/bash

total=0
list=(100 75 74 100 100)
for var in "${list[@]}"
do
    total=$((total + var))
done

average=$((total/5))
echo $average
```

Comment: Did you actually test this code? It outputs `0+/5`. Mathematical expressions aren't handled like that.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed to know Sampson-chen.

Comment: @demet8 there were some problems in the original version I had. I just tested the updated one and it works.

Comment: Except that now you've completely changed the input for the problem.

Comment: @Palpatim that doesn't affect the problem he's trying to solve. store1 ... store5 are hardcoded into the script. If it's actually input being piped into the script, a simple sed to remove the "storeX=" parts will suffice.

Comment: @Palpatim I didn't run it. I stepped through it here. Thought the script was doing what I had initially asked. I should have run it.

Comment: Be aware that since `bash` only does integer arithmetic, the computed average is only the integer part of the true average.